# Jolt Transformation - lowercase all keys in list of JSONs

Tags: json, list, lowercase, jolt

How to transform all the keys in this list of jsons to lowercase

```
[
  {
    "KEY01": "1111",
    "KEY02": "VALUE01",
    "KEY03": true
  },
  {
    "KEY01": "2222",
    "KEY02": "VALUE02",
    "KEY03": true
  }
]
```

desired result

```
[
  {
    "key01": "1111",
    "key02": "VALUE01",
    "key03": true
  },
  {
    "key01": "2222",
    "key02": "VALUE02",
    "key03": true
  }
]
```

I used this jolt transformation formula and it did only generate an object with values only being transformed to lowercase

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "=toLower"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Result

```
[{
    "KEY01": "1111",
    "KEY02": "value01",
    "KEY03": true
}, {
    "KEY01": "2222",
    "KEY02": "value02",
    "KEY03": true
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired result:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "$": "[&2].&1.key",
          "@": "[&2].&1.value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "key": "=toLower"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "value": "[&2].@(1,key)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Produces the following:

```
[ 
   {
     "key01" : "1111",
     "key02" : "VALUE01",
     "key03" : true
   }, 
   {
     "key01" : "2222",
     "key02" : "VALUE02",
     "key03" : true
   }
]
```